# Speeding Up Gazebo Physics Simulation (Considering ROS Plugin usage)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear All,

I was not sure whether to post this question here or on ROS answers page. But I think it is closer to gazebo than ROS.

My Objectives is to Speed up Physical simulation to the max speed (I use **max_step_size=0.005** and **real_time_update_rate=0.0**). I have around **25x** speed up with a Pioneer 2 robot with a single camera, 4x bumper and an IMU sensor (NVIDIA Geforce GTX980 with i7-4790@3.60 GHz x8). I use Gazebo 2.2.3 which comes with ROS indigo.

I need MORE! The reason is that I do Reinforcement learning experiments with robots, and well, faster experiments mean easier life.

**What I Need to have for My robot**

- Diff drive ( I use libgazebo_ros_diff_drive )
- Camera ( liggazebo_ros_camera)
- 4x Bumpers (I use 4 different link connected to chassis with libgazebo_ros_bumper)
- IMU ( I use libgazebo_ros_imu or libhector_gazebo_ros_imu)

**My Questions:**

- Why the speed of simulation drops so much when a robot is added? I have around 100x speed when an environment is loaded without a robot. Is this because of ROS plugins?
- Does anyone know of any faster ROS plugins if they are the bottleneck?
- Is there any other way for me to update the speed further without increasing more max_step_size?
- Is there perhaps a faster physics engine that I can use? I tried bullet, but nothing really changed.

**Notes**

- I already use very simple collision meshes both for my environment and my robot.
- My environment texture does not use lighting reflection/effects.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12477/speeding-up-gazebo-physics-simulation-(considering-ros-plugin-usage)/) by [shantia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2429/shantia/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

- Simulation slows down when a robot is added because the collision detection and dynamics engines now have work to do.
- The bottleneck is most likely not ROS plugins. You can always profile the code using valgrind, or some other tool.
- There is not an easy way to speed up simulation without changing the `max_step_size`. You can try a newer version of Gazebo (version 2 is over two years old).

As an alternative, you could run multiple simulations in parallel.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shantia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2429/shantia/) on 2016-02-02**:
I see. Does gazebo use CPU to calculate the collision and dynamic engines or GPU? Because my GPU utilization is at 8%, while gazebo is using 4 of my 8 CPU cores (4 processes with usage 2.5+1.0+0.55+0.18 CPUs based on htop results).
I will try installing the latest version. I am already using 10 machines to run separate simulations. Is it possible to run multiple gazebo's on the same machine?

**Comment by [shantia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2429/shantia/) on 2016-02-02**:
I did increase the max_step_size to 0.01 (it means 100Hz update rate, right?), and I have the following problem: After some time, the gazebo SensorManager.cc gives an assertion failure. It says "Took over 1.0 seconds to update a sensor". I have to see whether this happens on gazebo7 as well or not.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-02-02**:
Yes, the CPU is used by the collision and dynamic engines. the GPU is used by image-based sensors. The assertion you mention is an error that we are working on fixing.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-02-02**:
Pull request that fixes the assert problem: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/2115

**Comment by [shantia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2429/shantia/) on 2016-02-03**:
Oh, great thanks. I guess then this is it. I got my answer. Thank you for you efforts.

**Comment by [shantia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2429/shantia/) on 2016-02-04**:
I can confirm that with Gazebo 7.0 (compiled from source), I have no sensor assert problems, and I could speed up a very simple Pioneer 2 DX up to 430 times the real time speed with max_step_size of 0.05.

**Comment by [Deastan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/13558/deastan/) on 2019-07-09**:
@shantia,
Did you try to increase more the speed of a simulation ? I would like to be more faster.
This link is broken..:https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/2115 What was on it ? Did you tried to have multiple simulation on one computer ?